# Can't update from El Capitan public beta

Tags: macos, software-update, beta-seed-program

I took part in the public beta of El Capitan but now that the official version has been released I can't get it to update. If I go to Updates in the App Store I get "No Updates Available" and if I try installing from the OS's page, I get the option to download the installer instead.

I'm guessing that A) there are differences between the last public beta and the release so there should be an update, and B) since I can't find any other mention of this issue, something is messed up on my machine preventing it from seeing the update.

Should I bite the bullet and download and run the installer or is there something I can change to get my machine to update?

[image: Screenshot showing machine on 10.11 Beta with no updates available in the Mac App Store.]

Comment: What about timemachine backup and fresh install (Command R), restore from timemachine?

Comment: Having the same problem, too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ended up working was searching for "El Capitan" in the Mac App Store, clicking "Download", clicking "Continue", and running the downloaded installer.  Now that 10.11.2 is out, I'm getting the expected items in the Update tab so things appear be back to normal.

[image: Screenshot showing the download button in the Mac App Store.]

Answer (score 3):

Go to the Purchased page and click UPDATE there.

Comment: On the Purchased page, it also shows up as "Download" instead of "Update".

Comment: Ok, that's weird. Do you still have the installer in /Applications, maybe it's looking for that? If not, then I don't know.

Comment: Nope, never had the installer.  I did all the public beta updates through the App Store.  New versions always appeared in "Updates" up to the El Capitan final release.

Comment: Ok, guess I don't know then, sorry. I'd just download the released installer at this point, although I realize it's big.

Comment: It says: "OS X v10.11 is already installed on this computer. Use the Updates page to install the 10.11 update or if you would like to download the full OS X installer click Continue."  :/
https://www.dropbox.com/s/9zstlvlcwqc75a1/Screenshot%202015-11-03%2022.43.53.png?dl=0